# SQL Query - Filtered value from specific rows into result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I store invoices of spent fuel and the km's where the car was refueled, with the following structure:

[image]

My goal is to obtain a result like the following, so I can calculate the spent km's beetween invoices.

[image]

Any advice regarding how I can structure the query to get the desired result?

Comment: Are these all records about a single car?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you use?

Comment: yes @Kaf, only related to a single car.

Comment: @KevinBrydon, Really?

Comment: @KevinBrydon Do you see that OP is edited and can you compare the times?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan fair enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Date,
       (SELECT MAX(Kms) FROM invoices i2 WHERE i2.Kms < i1.Kms) AS StartKm,
        Kms AS FinishKm
FROM invoices i1
ORDER BY Kms
```

See: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f631/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH Invoices AS 
(
    SELECT 456 AS Invoice, '2013-03-01' AS [Date], 145000 AS Kms
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 658 AS Invoice, '2013-03-04' AS [Date], 145618 AS Kms
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 756 AS Invoice, '2013-03-06' AS [Date], 146234 AS Kms
), OrderedInvoices AS
(
    SELECT Invoice, [Date], Kms, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS RowNum
    FROM Invoices
)

SELECT i1.[Date], i2.Kms AS StartKms, i1.Kms AS FinishKms
FROM OrderedInvoices AS i1
LEFT JOIN OrderedInvoices AS i2
    ON i1.RowNum = i2.RowNum + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTE` and `Row_number()`:

```
;with cte as (
   select Invoice, [Date], kms, row_number() over(order by [date]) rn
   from yourTable
)

select c1.[Date], c2.kms StartKms, c1.kms EndKms
from cte c1 left join cte c2 on c1.rn  = c2.rn +1
order by c1.[Date]
```